# How did the Endeavour rescue SG-1?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

At the end of the episode "Serpent's Lair", SG-1 and Bratak win the day against Apophis' planned attack on Earth, but find themselves essentially stranded in orbit aboard crippled death gliders. The US space shuttle *Endeavour* appears, then we cut to the happy ending scene in the Gate Room.

How was *Endeavour* actually able to help them? There's no way to exit the gliders without being exposed to space and no means of docking, nor do they have space suits with them.

***Are we to assume the still-occupied gliders were simply placed into the cargo bay and then rode down that way?***

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a good reason why that wouldn't be the case. Both ships were relatively low on power but the key concern seems to be that they're going to burn up in the atmosphere rather than there being any shortage of air.

Since we know that gliders can [fold their wings](https://www.stargate-fusion.com/sg1/pics/episode/121/galerie/big/121_086.jpg) and since there's enough space in the shuttle for both gliders, it seems sensible that they were put into the (unpressurised) cargo hold and then landed as normal.

> **CARTER:** *Same here, sir. But I don't think we bought ourselves much time. **Our glider's had it.***
>
> **TEAL'C:** *I concur.*
>
> **CARTER:** *We got cooked pretty bad in the explosion.*
>
> **O'NEILL:** *Captain?*
>
> **CARTER:** ***We're low on power and in a fairly low orbit, so I don't imagine it will be too much longer before we burn up in Earth's
>   atmosphere.***

---

According to the MGM-Licensed "[Stargate SG-1 Goauld Death Glider Collector Scale Replica"](https://www.entertainmentearth.com/prodinfo.asp?number=QMSG1001B), the Death-Glider's [dimensions](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Glider#cite_note-model-1) are 45.9ft x 27.99ft x 14ft. With the wings fully folded and stowed, the dimensions would shrink to 15ft x 27.99ft x 14ft. That being the case, there would be sufficient space in the Shuttle's cargo hold to store both gliders (stacked sideways) with a few feet left over.

[image: Death Glider replica]

[image: ship schematics]

Comment: Assuming they could be secured properly... sideways would be an uncomfortable and perhaps hazardous way to ride the re-entry G-forces, and "in the dark" would be kinda scary I should think, but better than the alternative, I suppose.

Comment: @AnthonyX - The glider has artificial gravity, Being sideways makes no difference, nor do the g-forces and the craft has its own internal lighting.

Comment: "In the dark" was metaphorical - no view or instrumentation to what's going on around them once the bay doors are closed.

Comment: @AnthonyX - They clearly have an audio hookup though. Plus they're already in low orbit which means that they'd be on the ground in less than two hours; https://www.livescience.com/33402-how-land-space-shuttle-atlantis.html

Comment: Except for getting unloaded, and clearing customs and immigration!   Anyway maybe that's *why* the gliders were built to that dimension, or the Shuttle.  Standard space-going containers.

Comment: @AnthonyX If they really wanted to, they could have left the gliders when the bay pressurised. I'd expect the ride to be more comfy *inside* the gliders, though - inertial dampeners and all that. Also note that the gliders were recovered (they were referenced later in the show), so they certainly didn't just take the guys and leave the gliders out there.

Comment: @Luaan The space shuttle's cargo bay isn't pressurized.The doors are not air tight and the bay actually has open vents so that atmosphere remains equalized with the exterior since it's not strong enough to maintain pressure. They pretty much had to stay in the gliders the whole way down.

Comment: @Luaan I suppose the writers could have hand-waved into existence the capability that the shuttle cargo bay can be pressurized (in the Stargate universe), but the real space shuttle can't do that. I assumed that they weren't trying to fictionalize shuttle features and capabilities - beyond prep for a rescue mission in a matter of mere hours.

Comment: @KevinFee You're right, my bad. That makes the gliders even *more* comfortable :D